# Use of EOX in PHP function

Tags: php

I came across a php function that returns an XSL sheet and was wondering what is "**<<< eox**" I get that the function returns the sheet I just haven't seen that "tag" before. Thanks!

sample:

```
function getStylesheetData() { 
return <<< eox
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   xsl functions...
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   
eox;
}
```

link to the question that I referenced for more info:
[PHP code to sort XML tags alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076618/php-code-to-sort-xml-tags-alphabetically)

Comment: It's called a [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC) string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the syntax for a [heredoc string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: `<<<`. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

So in your example, the *eox* is just an identifier that can be replaced with something else.

Comment: That explains why searching for EOX only brings up chemotherapy treatments.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't `EOX`, it is just identifier and can be named anything. That syntax is know as [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). The prototype of it is:

```
<<< FOO
 some stuff here
 some more stuff here
FOO;
```

The **important** thing to notice when using `heredoc` syntax is that ending identifier (`FOO;` in above example) should not have any *space/tab/indentation* before it. For example:

```
// This will not work
    <<< FOO
    some stuff here
    some more stuff here
    FOO;

// This will work
    <<< FOO
    some stuff here
    some more stuff here
FOO;
```