# How to sort a xml file using DOM

Tags: php, xml, sorting

I have a xml file structured like

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>  <library>
> <book id="1003">
>     <title>Jquery MVC</title>
>     <author>Me</author>
>     <price>500</price>
> </book>
> <book id="1001">
>     <title>Php</title>
>     <author>Me</author>
>     <price>600</price>
> </book>
> <book id="1002">
>     <title>Where to use IFrame</title>
>     <author>Me</author>
>     <price>300</price>
> </book>
> </library>
> ```

In order to sort this xml according to the book id,

after reviewing [**this method from stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359224/sort-xml-via-attribute-value-php)

i coded like this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('DOM.xml');
$library = $dom->documentElement;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('/library/book');
function sort_trees($t1,$t2){
    return strcmp($t1['id'], $t2['id']);    
}

usort($result, 'sort_trees');
print_r($result);*/
```

But it gives me an error

> Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /var/www/html/testphp/phpxml/readxml.php on line 24

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer you cite is for SimpleXML, but you are using DOMDocument.

If you want to continue to use DOMDocument you need to keep its API in mind.

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('DOM.xml');
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$booklist = $xp->query('/library/book');

// Books is a DOMNodeList, not an array.
// This is the reason for your usort() warning.

// Copies DOMNode elements in the DOMNodeList to an array.
$books = iterator_to_array($booklist);

// Second, your sorting function is using the wrong API
// $node['id'] is SimpleXML syntax for attribute access.
// DOMElement uses $node->getAttribute('id');
function sort_by_numeric_id_attr($a, $b)
{
    return (int) $a->getAttribute('id') - (int) $b->getAttribute('id');
}

// Now usort()
usort($books, 'sort_by_numeric_id_attr');

// verify:
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->C14N(), "\n";
}
```

If you need to create a new output document with the nodes sorted, create a new document, import the root element, then import the book nodes in sorted order and add to the document.

```php
$newdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$libraries = $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($dom->documentElement));
foreach ($books as $book) {
    $libraries->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($book, true));
}

echo $newdoc->saveXML();
```

However, a much better approach is to use XSLT:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- file "sort_by_numeric_id.xsl" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
            <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then use XSLTProcessor (or `xsltproc` from the command line):

```php
$xsltdoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsltdoc->load('sort_by_numeric_id.xsl');

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStyleSheet($xsltdoc);

// You can now use $xslt->transformTo*() methods over and over on whatever documents you want

$libraryfiles = array('library1.xml', 'library2.xml');

foreach ($libraryfiles as $lf) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($lf);

    // write the new document
    $xslt->transformToUri($doc, 'file://'.preg_replace('/(\.[^.]+)?$/', '-sorted$0', $lf, 1);

    unset($doc); // just to save memory
}
```

Comment: loadXML has gave an error so i changed into load.

But the result not sorted

Comment: What is your output? I tested this replacing `$x` with the xml string and got a sorted result.

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /var/www/html/testphp/phpxml/readxml.php on line 4

Comment: You are doing something very basic wrong with loading your XML. Your XML may not be a string, or the string may be invalid. `->load('filename.xml')` loads a file, `->loadXML('<root/>')` loads a string.

Comment: [ZVON](http://zvon.org/comp/m/xslt.html) has a good set of resources. Start with [the XSLT tutorial](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XSLT_1.html). Ignore XSLT 2 because it is not supported by PHP and most open-source software.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and response

Comment: `$dom->loadXML(file_load_contents('filename.xml'))`  does *exactly the same thing* as `$dom->load('filename.xml')`. It doesn't matter which you use.

Answer (score 0):

(copied over from your duplicate question)  This works

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('dom.xml');
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$booklist = $xp->query('/library/book');
$books = iterator_to_array($booklist);


function sort_by_numeric_id_attr($a, $b)
{
    return (int) $a->getAttribute('id') - (int) $b->getAttribute('id');
}


usort($books, 'sort_by_numeric_id_attr');

$newdom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$newdom->formatOutput = true;
$root = $newdom->createElement("library");
$newdom->appendChild($root);
foreach ($books as $b) {
    $node = $newdom->importNode($b,true);
    $root->appendChild($newdom->importNode($b,true));
}

$newdom->save('DOM2.xml');
```

As you can see, you need to create a new DOMDocument, and add the sorted children to it (via importNode to copy the DOMNodes from one DOMDocument to another).