# how to sort xml data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

This is my sample xml

```
<markers>
    <marker location_id="1" title="test 1" distance="0.0832"/>
    <marker location_id="2" title="test 2" distance="3.1852"/>
    <marker location_id="3" title="test 3" distance="4.3761"/>
    <marker location_id="4" title="test 4" distance="3.3761"/>
</markers>
```

```js
var entries = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
```

How can I sort this entries by distance, ascending order ? I want to do it using Javascript.

Comment: may be this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359224/sort-xml-via-attribute-value-php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sort` method:

```
var $markers = $('.marker', xml);
$markers.find('marker').sort(function(a, b) {
     return parseFloat($(a).attr('distance')) > parseFloat($(b).attr('distance'));
}).appendTo($markers);
```

This code assumes that the XML you have is stored in the `xml` variable.

Comment: please add the code that loads the xml into `xml` variable. and where is `$marker` variable?

Comment: var entries = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

after this, how can i use this ?

var $markers = $('.marker', xml);
$markers.find('marker').sort(function(a, b) {
     return parseFloat($(a).attr('distance')) > parseFloat($(b).attr('distance'));
}).appendTo($marker);

at the end, i am using loop to get the data.

 for(i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) { 
.....
}

Comment: @machineaddict `xml` is a variable in the OPs original code example, so I would assume he already has that. `$marker` was a typo which I have now corrected.